# Merge csv files, add original file name to each row in output file

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have multiple csv files in a folder with the same data structure,

```
0.00;1.05;10.5
0.01;2.05;15.5
0.02;3.05;20.5
...
```

I want ot merge all the csv files to 1 summary file and add a column with file name to each line depanding on the original data source.

```
0.00;1.05;10.5;csv1.csv
0.01;2.05;15.5;csv1.csv
0.02;3.05;20.5;csv1.csv
0.00;5.05;0.05;csv2.csv
0.01;6.05;1.05;csv2.csv
0.02;7.05;2.05;csv2.csv
...
```

I managed to merge the files, but cant find a way to add the file names.

```
files = []
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        files.append(file)
with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as fw:
        cw = csv.writer(fw)
        for file in files:
            with open(file, newline='') as f:
                cr = csv.reader(islice(f,13,None)
                cw.writerows(cr)
```

I dont want to use pandas concat due to ram limitations.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse the input csv files, just append a delimiter and then the current file name to each line. You can use the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) module:

```
import fileinput
from pathlib import Path

folder = '.'        # set accordingly, assume current directory
path = Path(folder)
with fileinput.input(files=path.glob('*.csv')) as f, open('results.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in f:
        print(';'.join([line.rstrip('\n'), fileinput.filename().name()]), file=outfile)
```

Regarding your code, you can fix it like this:

```
import os
import csv

folder = '.'
files = []
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        files.append(file)

with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as fw:
        cw = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=';')
        for file in files:
            with open(file, newline='') as f:
                for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=';'):
                    row.append(file)
                    cw.writerow(row)
```

Here the `delimiter` argument is set to semi-colon because the default delimiter is comma and your files are using `;`. That will fix the proper parsing of the input csv files, and use `;` for the output file. Then each input file is processed by reading each line and appending the filename to the row list. Finally the new row is written to the output CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os` and `pandas`:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

basedir = <path of your base folder>

all_dfs = []
for filename in filter(lambda f: os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.csv', next(os.walk(basedir))[2]):
    curr_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(basedir, filename), sep=';', header=None)
    curr_df['filename'] = filename
    all_dfs.append(curr_df)

pd.concat(all_dfs, axis=0).to_csv('merged_cvs.csv', sep=';', header=False, index=False)
```

Or if you prefer in only one line:

```py
pd.concat([pd.concat((df, pd.DataFrame([f for _ in range(len(df))])), axis=1) for f, df in
    ((filename, pd.read_csv(os.path.join(basedir, filename), sep=';', header=None))
    for filename in filter(lambda f: os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.csv', next(os.walk(basedir))[2]))
]).to_csv('merged_cvs.csv', sep=';', header=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
files = []
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        files.append(file)
with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as fw:
    cw = csv.writer(fw)
    for file in files:
        with open(file, newline='') as f:
            fw.write(f"{file}\n")  # just write the filename before the content :)
            cr = csv.reader(islice(f,13,None)
            cw.writerows(cr)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. But I am getting and error: `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`